# javax.ejb.EJBException: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not execute statement

Tags: mysql, jpa

i'm getting this error:

```
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Incorrect integer value: 'ANTIQUES Value 1' for column 'category' at row 1
```

after selecting a value from selectOneMenu and trying to save the entity into database; the selectOneMenu is populated with SelectItemGroup:

```
private List<SelectItem> options = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();

    public CategoryBean()
    {
        SelectItemGroup group1 = new SelectItemGroup("ANTIQUES");
        group1.setSelectItems(new SelectItem[] {
            new SelectItem("ANTIQUES Value 1", "European Antiques"),
            new SelectItem("ANTIQUES Value 1", "Asian Antiques"),
            new SelectItem("ANTIQUES Value 2", "Furniture"),
            new SelectItem("ANTIQUES Value 3", "Books and Manuscripts"),
            new SelectItem("ANTIQUES Value 3", "Architecture")
        });
        options.add(group1);

        SelectItemGroup group2 = new SelectItemGroup("ART");
        group2.setSelectItems(new SelectItem[] {
            new SelectItem("ART Value 1", "PAINTINGS"),
            new SelectItem("ART Value 4", "HANDMADE ART"),
            new SelectItem("ART Value 5", "PHOTOS")
        });
        options.add(group2);
```

..

and the selected value is stored as a String in the entity table

Any idea? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: 'ANTIQUES Value 1' is not `integer` value. Seems like table column has `int` type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the `@Entity` bean and at table definition (especially at the column `category`).
According to your log, seems like `category` is defined like `String` in entity bean, but `integer` in table.
So, either define table column like `varchar` or define field `category` in bean like `int` and correct class for menu items.